# learning how to use pretty-faces

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I'm starting with PrettyFaces and i would like a url like this:

`"/project/car/alter/120" -- this is pretty link.`

But when i send a GET request in JSF i got this:

```
"/project/car?action=alter&id=120"
```

If i make this in pretty-config.xml:

```
<url-mapping>
        <pattern value="/car/#{action}/#{id}" />
        <view-id value="/car?action=alter&id=120" />
    </url-mapping>
```

This don't work because i can't generate the "pattern" link. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not hard-code your parameter values in the url-mapping configuration. It should look like this:

```
<url-mapping>
    <pattern value="/car/#{action}/#{id}" />
    <view-id value="/car.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

Next, you should use  to generate your URLs in your XHTML pages:

http://www.ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/outbound_rewriting.html#jsf

```
<h:link outcome="/car" value="View car>
    <f:param name="action" value="view" />
    <f:param name="id" value="231" />
</h:link>
```

Does this answer your question?